# Simple Application that executes every 15 minutes. How can I stop it from disturbing any Windows?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Basically, I have an application that runs every 15 minutes. I would like this Console application to remain hidden and not for example minimise/disturb full screen applications.

What would be the best way to accomplish this, it can't be a service though. I'm writing the console application in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your reasons for not making it a service?

Comment: Project + Properties, Output type = Windows application.  Done.  Not that it is necessary, scheduled tasks run in your own desktop.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I can think of several reasons.  Services are more complex, for starters.  Plus you either have to run it under the SYSTEM account, which has drawbacks, or set it up to run under another account, which means creating a new user, maintaining the password, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run an application every 15 minutes use a scheduled task. The very simple way to avoid any window being shown is to make this a normal GUI app rather than a console app, but arrange that you do not show any windows in your GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

like david said if you make it a gui program but never load any windows it will run in the background with nothing ever popping up or showing or anything.. another option would be to have your application run continuously and have it do something every 15 minutes...

Comment: Yeah, `sleep(15*60*1000)` would do the job of waiting for 15 minutes. But the downside is that the user could kill the process, or it may crash, and then you would lose service. That's why a task makes sense in my view.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the scheduled task run as a different user, Network Service maybe, depends on your needs. This will force it to run under the specificed users context and will not show up on other logged in users screens.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything.  A console application is invisible and doesn't interact with other windows.  The only way to even know it's there is through Task Manager or something similar.

Comment: Right okay then, I thought it displayed a command prompt style window.

Comment: Huh?  A console app shows nothing unless it creates a window.

Comment: Wha? Console apps automatically create a console window when they start whether or not you display anything in it.  This minimal C# program flickers a console window when run: `namespace Empty { class Empty { static void Main(string[] args) { } } }`
Am I misunderstanding what you mean?  Or are you thinking a of a GUI app without a displayed window like @DavidHeffernan mentioned?

Comment: That's Windows creating the console window by default, not the app.  Simply launching it via CreateProcess with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW and/or DETACHED_PROCESS flags gives you no window.

Comment: @Carey That is correct but non-trivial to achieve with a scheduled task